# JSON Array in Flex

Tags: apache-flex, arrays, json

I have code:

```
api_result = '{"response":[{"uid":1969258,"first_name":"Walle","last_name":"Woo"}]}'; 
var myobj:Object = JSON.decode(api_result);
```

So, how I can get uid, first_name and last_name from "response" array?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var UID:Object = myobj.response[0].uid;

var firstName:Object = myobj.response[0].first_name;

var lastName:Object = myobj.response[0].last_name;
```

Comment: Can also type those to String and cast them:
var lastName:String = myobj.response[0].last_name as String;